# Parameterized query in Oracle trouble

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I'm using `Oracle.DataAccess` rather than the obsolete `System.Data.OracleClient` and I seem to be having trouble passing multiple parameters to my update query

This works

```
OracleCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE db SET column1 = :param1 WHERE column2 = 'Y'"
OracleCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("param1", "1234"))
```

But I want to be able to pass multiple parameters

Here's my full code

```
    OracleConn.Open()
    OracleCommand = OracleConn.CreateCommand()
    OracleCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE db SET column1 = :param1 WHERE column2 = :param2"
    OracleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    OracleCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("param1", "1234"))
    OracleCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("param2", "Y"))
    OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

My `SELECT` query seems to work when passing multiple parameters but not the update one

Comment: You did execute the SQL statement with OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()?

Comment: What is your OracleCommand.CommandType

Comment: @Codo I have the `OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` in there just forgot to put it in my example

Comment: @Cos Callis I have set it like this `OracleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text`

Comment: ...and which Oracle Client are you using?

Comment: See my update - it seems to work only with one parameter?

Comment: Does it work with the other parameter only?

Comment: it works with either parameter but only one at a time

Comment: Can you post the full section of data access code (the initialization of the conneciton, command, etc)? Also, have you tried multiple parameters on a select statement to see if you get a different result?

Comment: What is the column type of column2?

Comment: Column2 and Column1 are both varchars

Comment: @Zach Green i've updated the question with the full code i'm using - the `select` statement seems to work with multiple parameters but not the `update` - it seems to me like it is overwriting the first parameter with the second one

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Although I can't see anything wrong with your example, I wonder if you're being hit by the old `BindByName` problem.  By default, ODP.NET binds parameters to the query in the order in which they are added to the collection, rather than based on their name as you'd like.  Try setting `BindByName` to `true` on your `OracleCommand` object and see if that fixes the problem.

I've had this problem so many times that I use my own factory method to create commands which automatically sets this property to `true` for me.

Classic useless Oracle documentation [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleCommandClass.htm#DAFCJDDG)

Comment: Beat me to it. Exactly what I was thinking once I saw that select is working fine.

Comment: Genius! That's fixed it - Thank you so much it's been doing my head in for the last week!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Have you an idea what can one do if one is using the generic *ADO.NET* interface (`DbCommand` *&c*) instead of the strongly typed one (`OracleCommand` *&c*)? Is it perhaps possible to specify it in the connection string?..

Comment: My question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7282843/2862241).

Answer (score 4):

To emulate the default behavior of the System.Data.OracleClient, you should set the OracleCommand to bind by name.

```
OracleCommand.BindByName = True
```

Answer (score 2):

Try newing up your OracleParameter with a the type specified. Set the value of the object before adding it to the parameters list.

```
var param1 = new OracleParameter( "param1", OracleType.Int32 );
param1.Value = "1234";

OracleCommand.Parameters.Add( param1 );
```

Comment: The colon should not be used in the first parameter in the OracleParameter constructor. Should be OracleParameter("param1",...

Comment: Good call Zach. I must have been looking at older documentation.

OracleParameter Class documentation
http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/B28089_01/OracleParameterClass.htm

Comment: If you update your answer, I believe I can remove the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hope it works. It does compile.
Not sure if you also have to send a commit...
I always do this sort of thing through a stored procedure, so I have a commit after the update statement in the stored procedure.

Harvey Sather

```
        OracleConnection ora_conn = new OracleConnection("connection string");

        OracleCommand ora_cmd = new OracleCommand("UPDATE db SET column1 = :param1 WHERE column2 = :param2", ora_conn);
        ora_cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        ora_cmd.BindByName = true;

        ora_cmd.Parameters.Add(":param1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, "1234", ParameterDirection.Input);
        ora_cmd.Parameters.Add(":param2", OracleDbType.Varchar2, "Y", ParameterDirection.Input);

        ora_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

The first code block is correct: use a colon in front of the parameter name, but not in the first argument to OracleParameter.

If no errors are thrown, it could be that the UPDATE runs successfully, it just doesn't update any records based on the WHERE clause and its substituted parameter value. Try doing it on a test table with no WHERE clause in the UPDATE to make sure it does something.

Comment: I took the WHERE clause out and it still didn't run - if i change the query without parameters then it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Here's the type of structure I usually use (sorry, this is from memory) :

```
int rows = 0;
using ( OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString) ) {
  using ( OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand() ) {
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE table SET column1 = ':p1 WHERE column2 = :p2";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":p1", p1Val);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":p2", p2Val);
    rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

The key difference is the use of the AddWithValue - I don`t remember why I ended up using that, but do remember having problems with some of the other ways of doing it.

Comment: I think i tried using `AddWithValue` but it isn't in the `Oracle.DataAccess` namespace - I  think its in the `System.OracleClient` namespace but that is obsolete

Comment: That depends on what version of the framework you're using.  System.OracleClient is no longer going to be supported by Microsoft, but that doesn't mean you have to stop using it.

Comment: I'm using .Net 4 framework - I wanted something that would be future proof preferably