# Is it ok to still use System.Data.OracleClient even though its obsolete?

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I've been using `System.Data.OracleClient` for a while now and i'm not sure whether I should keep using it if it is being deprecated?

Although all my pages will still work under the .Net 4 framework i'm worried that when there is a new framework all the pages may stop working.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I am having trouble with adding multiple parameters using the `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` namespace and am wondering whether I should go back to using `System.Data.OracleClient`

Comment: you shouldn't be having a problem adding multiple parameters. Post a question with code examples to SO so someone can help.

Comment: @Zach Green I've posted a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980615/parametized-query-in-oracle-trouble - unfortunately nothing seems to be working

Comment: I added a comment for more info. I will try to help. I use ODP.net with multiple parameters in all my apps, so I know it works. We just need to figure out why it is not working for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using it is still ok for now, but what is the future of the app? Do you plan for the application to be used and maintained for years in the future? If so, you should move to ODP.net so that you get updates and new features.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's recommendation is that you find a third-party client, such as [ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html).

> The types in System.Data.OracleClient are deprecated. The types are supported in version 4 of the .NET Framework but will be removed in a future release. Microsoft recommends that you use a third-party Oracle provider.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Using the Oracle DLLs has always performed better (quicker) for me.  While System.Data.OracleClient will remain in VS, I don't understand why you wouldn't want to use the Oracle DLLs.