# Not a legal OleAut date.. The exception was raised by the IDataReader interface

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, ssas-tabular

I have an SSAS Tabular project and the tables are coming from an Oracle database based on queries. When I proceed with process all, everything is fine but when I try to deploy the solution, the metadata is created successfully on the server and then deployment fails with the following error :

> Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'Not a
> legal OleAut date.. The exception was raised by the IDataReader
> interface.
>
> The database operation was cancelled because of an earlier failure.

[image]

I am using `System.Data.OracleClient` which is an ADO.NET provider. 6I have a doubt it may be outdated since when I connect to Power BI I get this message :
[image]

I checked all the date columns in my tables but I didn't find any value which is invalid (outside the valid range 1-January-1900  to 31-December-9999).

Comment: If you are pulling the same data in both places and one fails and the other works, I would start with drivers. That said, my experience with date issues is that you do have a date that's in an invalid format, but you may need to bring the column in as text to find it. Often it is a row or rows where month and day are swapped (mm/dd and dd/mm), though a year like 0023 for 2023 or maybe even the 9999 year could be causing this error with a different driver.

Comment: `System.Data.OracleClient` is deprecated for *quite* some time. Power BI isn't SSAS but it *does* tell you to use Oracle's .NET client instead. Try that, or Oracle's ODBC or OLEDB drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the driver. `System.Data.OracleClient` is deprecated [for 12 years at least](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058261/is-it-ok-to-still-use-system-data-oracleclient-even-though-its-obsolete) even though the [actual documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-and-adonet) has recent modification dates. Even the [ODBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/odbc-driver-for-oracle?view=sql-server-ver16) and [OLEDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-oracle?view=sql-server-ver16) drivers provided by Microsoft have deprecation warnings. All those drivers still exist to avoid breaking old code.

At the very least, try using Oracle's ODBC, OLEDB or .NET drivers instead.