# Adding Oracle parameter in an If statement not working

Tags: asp.net, oracle, parameters

This question branches off of my last question located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5980615/372364)

I can now add multiple parameters to my query but my next issue is that I am trying to add my parameter based on the `checked` status of my `checkbox`

Here's my code

```
OracleConn.Open()
OracleCommand = OracleConn.CreateCommand()
OracleCommand.BindByName = True
OracleCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE db SET column1 = :param1 WHERE column2 = :param2"
OracleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
OracleCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("param1", "1234"))

If cbCheckbox1.Checked = True Then
    OracleCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("param2", "Y"))
Else
    OracleCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("param2", "N"))
End If

OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

It doesn't error but it doesn't update the database either

If I take the `If` statement out and only have one parameter in like this

```
OracleCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("param2", "Y"))
```

Then it works fine

Is there something i'm doing wrong?

Any ideas?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does it throw an error?

Comment: @Dan it doesn't throw an error it does nothing at all but if I take the `If` statement out then it runs fine

Comment: Do you mean you remove the if block and replace it with just the parameter adding line? Which one?

Comment: If I remove the If block and replace it with either parameter adding line then it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by wrapping my checkbox databind in a `If Not Page.IsPostBack` and that fixed the problem