# Entity Framework with Oracle using odp.net not taking parameters in linq query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, odp.net

I am using EntityFramework with Oracle using odp.net. The parameterized sql query does not work.

```
var orderCode = "XYZ";
var set = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<Order>(
    "Select * from dwh.Orders where OrderCode = '{0}'"
    , orderCode
);
```

(or)

```
var set1 = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<Order>(
    "Select * from dwh.Orders where OrderCode = ':param'", 
    new OracleParameter("param", orderCode)
);

Console.WriteLine(set.Count() + ", " + set1.Count()); //Gives 0, 0
```

However, if I have hard code the value, it works.

```
var set = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<Order>(
    "Select * from dwh.Orders where OrderCode = 'XYZ'",
    orderCode
);
```

Does any one know why? I have 150 columns in that view. Is that a problem?

**UPDATE:**
The query with the Oracle parameter works. The problem is that I had single quotes around the :param variable.

That being said, top query with '{0}' does not work. Also, the following linq query does not work.

```
var set = ctx.Orders.Where(a => a.OrderCode == orderCode); // Gets zero results.
```

When I hardcode the value, it works and fetches the results correctly.

```
var set = ctx.Orders.Where(a => a.OrderCode == "XYZ"); // Gets the results correctly.
```

**UPDATE 2:**
The queries work with dotconnect driver from Devart. Looks like this is an issue with odp.net.

Anyone has similar problems?

Comment: Can you explain "does not work" better?  Are you getting an exception, an empty result, or the wrong results?

Comment: Does it work if you use `a.OrderCode.Equals(orderCode)`

Comment: .Equals doesn't work either.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem.  I don't want to reference the ODP driver in my application (that's why I have EF), so this is irksome.  For now, I'm probably going to do the anti-pattern of concatenating the SQL.  The parameter is entirely internal to the application, so SQL Injection won't be a problem.  Still, it leaves a bad taste in my mouth.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you truncated your example, but if you are using multiple parameters, this might be the problem:

[Parameterized query in Oracle trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980615/parameterized-query-in-oracle-trouble)

> Although I can't see anything wrong with your example, I wonder if you're being hit by the old BindByName problem. By default, ODP.NET binds parameters to the query in the order in which they are added to the collection, rather than based on their name as you'd like. Try setting BindByName to true on your OracleCommand object and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when using strings in connection with Oracle as it has the quirk to pad strings that are defined as `CHAR` (read [CHAR versus VARCHAR2 Semantics](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/b_char.htm) for details).

Lets assume you have defined `OrderCode` as `CHAR(4)` with a value of `XYZ` then PL/SQL blank-pads the value to the declared length which results in `XYZ_` (whereas `_` is the padding character here).

Also assume that the *non-constant* string `orderCode` is treated as `VARCHAR2` due to this statement in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/b_char.htm):

> If either value in a comparison has datatype VARCHAR2,
>   non-blank-padding semantics are used. That is, when comparing
>   character values of unequal length, PL/SQL makes no adjustments and
>   uses the exact lengths.

Now if you try to do a `a.OrderCode == orderCode` then the left side is `CHAR`and the right side is `VARCHAR2` and therefore `non-blank-padding` is used which results in `XYZ_` = `XYZ` returning `false`.

So the solution is to use something like `a.OrderCode.TrimEnd() == orderCode` to make the comparison work as `.TrimEnd()` is translated into the PL/SQL [`RTRIM()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions141.htm) function which returns a `VARCHAR2`.