# ssrs ORA_01008:NOT ALL VALIABLE BOUNDED

Tags: reporting-services, ora-01008

I have a proble with binding parameters in a report 
I've done these steps:
1-created a parametrized query
2-created a report and bonded its internal dataset
When I bind my report parameters with shared dataset parameters I face this error while viewing report :
ORA_01008:NOT ALL VALIABLE BOUNDED
Tip:
My report connects to oracle using ole db..

Comment: This has been discussed a number of times on SO, including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493028/ora-01008-not-all-variables-bound-they-are-bound).  Check the comments under the question here -- there's a checklist for fixing the issue.  Likely related to the query.

Comment: Thank you so much.It helped.I removed the comments now it works,so strange !