# I am getting ORA-01008: not all variables bound error while updating

Tags: c#, spring, oracle

Dont know what I am doing wrong. can anyone help. Not even sure for which parameter I am getting this error.

```
var sql = @"
        UPDATE Test_Tem_Table  SET
            SOFTCLSD_IND = :SOFTCLSD_IND
          , SOFTCLSD_DT = :SOFTCLSD_DT
          , SOFTCLSD_BY = :SOFTCLSD_BY
          , SOFTCLSD_COMMENT = :SOFTCLSD_COMMENT
          , SOFTCLSD_LASTUPDT_BY = :SOFTCLSD_LASTUPDT_BY
          , SOFTCLSD_LASTUPDT_DT = :SOFTCLSD_LASTUPDT_DT 
        WHERE PREFIX_CB_ELIG_ID = :PREFIX_CB_ELIG_ID";

        var param = AdoTemplate.CreateDbParameters();
        param.Add("SOFTCLSD_IND", System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType.Char).Value = DBUtils.ConvertBoolToYN(currentSoftClose.IsSoftClosed);
        param.Add("SOFTCLSD_DT", System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType.DateTime).Value = ((DateTime)currentSoftClose.SoftClosedDate).Date;
        param.Add("SOFTCLSD_BY", System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType.VarChar).Value = currentSoftClose.SoftClosedBy;
        param.Add("SOFTCLSD_COMMENT", System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType.VarChar).Value = currentSoftClose.Comments;
        param.Add("SOFTCLSD_LASTUPDT_BY", System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType.VarChar).Value = currentSoftClose.SoftClosedLastUpdatedBy;
        param.Add("SOFTCLSD_LASTUPDT_DT", System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType.DateTime).Value = currentSoftClose.SoftClosedLastUpdatedDate == null ? (DateTime?)null : ((DateTime)currentSoftClose.SoftClosedLastUpdatedDate).Date;
        param.Add("PREFIX_CB_ELIG_ID", System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType.Number).Value = currentSoftClose.Id;

        return AdoTemplate.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.Text, sql, param);
```

Comment: Is the above code verbatim; you haven’t perhaps elided any comments in the SQL? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493028/ora-01008-not-all-variables-bound-they-are-bound

Comment: I am getting this error when I am passing null to SOFTCLSD_LASTUPDT_DT parameter.

Comment: Try a DBNull instead when it’s null.

Comment: currentSoftClose.SoftClosedLastUpdatedDate == null ? DBNull.Value : ((DateTime)currentSoftClose.SoftClosedLastUpdatedDate).Date; throwing error ni implict conversion between system.DBNull and System.DateTime

Comment: I’m out of ideas. You could bodge it if you’re under time pressure by switching on the nullness of the date and using different SQL and parameters for each, but it’s not a very satisfactory solution.

Comment: this one worked currentSoftClose.SoftClosedLastUpdatedDate ?? (object)DBNull.Value;