# How to add a new column with static values in SSRS report?

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to add a new column with some static values in SSRS report. I am using expression builder in SSRS report:

```
=IIF(Fields!BILLING_SERVICE_CD.Value="ASG1","75.28",
  IIF(Fields!BILLING_SERVICE_CD.Value="ASG2","92.66",
   IIF(Fields!BILLING_SERVICE_CD.Value="ASG3","124.87","")))
```

But it is giving me an error:

> ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Comment: That looks like a Oracle error. Are your parameters mapped to the Oracle query's variables?
Apparently there's also issues with Comments in the [WHERE clause in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493028/ora-01008-not-all-variables-bound-they-are-bound).

Comment: I agree with Hannover Fist - that is an Oracle error you are getting from your query, it doesn't relate to that expression. Can you post your SQL query?