# Replacing TableAdapters with Oracle.DataAccess.Client (ODP.NET)

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net, tableadapter, system.data.oracleclient

I have a legacy DAL with like 100 TableAdapters (DataSet xsd) but because we got new servers with Oracle client 12c I had to made the switch to the `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` (ODP.NET) from the old deprecated `System.Data.OracleClient`.

The only problem I have now is that I always get an error: **ORA-01008: Not all variables bound** when calling the Table Adapters.

I read that I have to set `BindByName` to `true` in `OracleCommand` for each TableAdapter. But how can I do that when the only place where `OracleCommand` is used is in the designer of the TableAdapter itself?

Is there some way to do this without extending each TableAdapter, because I have like 100 of them.

Comment: So, you say, this is designer. This means that on each of your form or control you have one? How about using some data access layer?

Comment: As I said, this is a legacy codebase which wasn't designed very well in the beginning. There is a DAL with the TableAdapters, then there is a BLL with WCF services which returns those TableAdapters, so all the TableAdapters go all the way up to the UI. But that's not a concern now, as we are trying to move one step at a time, and this time it's switching from deprecated `System.Data.OracleClient` to new `Oracle.DataAccess.Client`. But this `BindByName` is making it hard, because we have like 100 TableAdapters.

Comment: Can you post some code snippets with the exact code yielding that error?  It's possible the problem is not where you think it is.  I recall that System.Data.OracleClient was AWFUL at managing bind variables, although I don't recall if the syntax was that different from the mainstream ODP syntax.

Comment: As far as I can remember, `BindByName` is property of command, not adapter. Therefore, you can keep on passing your adapters as before. And all you need to do in your data access is replace each command with a method returning command and in this method do just one time for all code base "bindbyname"

Comment: @T.S. The OracleCommand is hardwired into each TableAdapter designer. That creates a problem.

Comment: But this is why you're programmer. Refactor the thing and make it reusable.

Comment: Yeah, I could extend each TableAdapter and add a function that sets `BindByName=true` on each item in the CommandCollection, but we're talking about well over 100 TableAdapters, so I was looking for some easier and more generic method.

Comment: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13949553/1053611) answer, could this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was I extended each TableAdapter and created a new `SetBindByName()` method, where I forced `BindByName = true` on the OracleCommand collection.

Like so...

```
public partial class V_CUSTOMER_GLOBALTableAdapter
{
    public void SetBindByName(bool value = true)
    {
        foreach (Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand cmd in this.CommandCollection)
        {
            cmd.BindByName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then when I created an instance of the TableAdapter, I called the new `SetBindByName()` method.

```
V_CUSTOMER_GLOBALTableAdapter ta = new V_CUSTOMER_GLOBALTableAdapter();
ta.SetBindByName(true);
```